# Calling Android Function using Jscript

Tags: android

i am creating a app in which i have to interface php page using android...

i am newbie in android dev...  i use the code given  in http://android-er.blogspot.in ..for demo using same code i create a small app and tried on emulator ...but after clicking on click button nothing is happening...also logcat is not displaying any error...

my app content these files...
1...java code for mainactivity
2....html code (save in apache server)
3...  main.xml contain web view

1---code for main activty..

```
package com.example.prac_jscript;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mybrowser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mybrowser =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1) ;

    mybrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyjavaScriptInterface(this), "AndroidFUNCTION");

     mybrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

     mybrowser.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.3/copy.html");
    }


    public class MyjavaScriptInterface{


        Context mContext;
        public MyjavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

             mContext = c;
        }

        public void openAndroidDialog(){
             AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
             = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
             myDialog.setTitle("DANGER!");
             myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want!");
             myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
             myDialog.show();
            }
    }

}
```

2 - code of html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <label>
    <input type="submit" value="Copy" onClick="openAndroidDialog()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function openAndroidDialog() {
     AndroidFunction.openAndroidDialog();
 }
</script>

    </label>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

please help me ...

Comment: Did you try to make it work with the exact same code as you referred to, before you altered it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to worry small mistake

change this line

```
mybrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyjavaScriptInterface(), "AndroidFUNCTION");
```

To

```
mybrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyjavaScriptInterface(), "AndroidFunction");
```

### UPDATE:

**Your `JavascriptInterface` Should like this**

```
 public class MyjavaScriptInterface{



        MyjavaScriptInterface() {

        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void openAndroidDialog(){
            AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
                    = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            myDialog.setTitle("DANGER!");
            myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want!");
            myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
            myDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**How to open watsapp?**

```
Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    if (waIntent != null) {
        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: same problem in that code,,last line of logcat...Starting TG #0, 0x2a22d308..and after that nothing is displaying...

Comment: help me the code which i refferd is here....http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/run-android-java-code-from-webpage.html

Comment: yes on device also only showing html..after clicking nothing is displaying,,,

Comment: thanks Biraj...finally done happy at the moment....also i am confused about context ,,can u elaborate why don't use context here...

Comment: context was not an issue. But it was non of use. @JavascriptInterface was required

Comment: now Biraj i want to open whats app installed on device...can i do that using this code..if it is so please tell me the way...

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Hi bro. Are you there?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia can you help me for that.?

Comment: Hello @Biraj...Please help me again.. i want to take data from javascript variable stored in php site which i included in webview..   after  a lots of search i am confused..read lot about http get & post..nothing is finallized yet..please help me...?

Comment: Hello biraj..please refer my question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832739/display-data-on-android-screen-using-webview-when-data-is-stored-as-javascript-

Answer (score 0):

The interface name is case-sensitive. These two don't match:

*mybrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyjavaScriptInterface(this), "**AndroidFUNCTION**");*

***AndroidFunction***.openAndroidDialog();

EDIT:

The [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) states that "*For applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above, only public methods that are annotated with JavascriptInterface can be accessed from JavaScript.*"

It also states that the interaction takes place on a background thread, so post any ui stuff on the main thread with [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

Comment: same problem occuring not displaying dialog in the code which i reffered from this post,,,please help...http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/run-android-java-code-from-webpage.html

Comment: hello kaka...please refer my question ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832739/display-data-on-android-screen-using-webview-when-data-is-stored-as-javascript-